# Add logo to UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm adding the following code to my app delegate to get my logo to the UINavigationBar, but it is not working. I have the Logo.png and Logo@2x.png inside the project.

What am I doing wrong?

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleView:titleView];
```

Comment: File names aren't case-sensitive in iOS are they? If they are that may be your problem. You say you have `logo` and `logo@2x.png` in your project. But in your code you are using `imageNamed:@"Logo.png"`. Just a stab in the dark as I can't remember one way or the other how case sesitivity is handled for files.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 seems like it is: http://partialclass.blogspot.fr/2009/04/iphone-sdk-device-is-case-sensitive.html

Comment: The images are cs. code fixed.

Comment: The code compiles fine but doesn't work.

Comment: Up. I have the same issue. appearance configuration for the title view doesn't work. It works only if you set it in a view directly :| strange

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS is case-sensitive. Try it again but change:

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
```

to

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
```

Comment: Wow. You said you solved the problem in the middle of my answer. Oh well. Glad you fixed your problem.

Comment: No I didn't said that. I said the image names are fine, I just typed wrong in so. The code still doesn't work. =/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you'll want to do is to set the tileImage in your ViewController's navigation item like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set up the nav bar
    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:titleImage];
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a global solution instead of writing the same code or a call the same code everytime.

Comment: Just create a base view controller. That way you only have to write the code once.